# How to parse nested column for CSV data in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue-spark

I am working on a database where the data is stored in csv format. The DB looks like the following:

| id | containertype | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CASE | {height=2.01, length=1.07, width=1.22} |
| 2 | PALLET | {height=1.80, length=1.07, width=1.23} |

I want to parse the data inside `size` column and create a pyspark df like:

| id | containertype | height | length | width |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CASE | 2.01 | 1.07 | 1.22 |
| 2 | PALLET | 1.80 | 1.07 | 1.23 |

I tried parsing the string to StructType and MapType but none of the approaches are working. Is there any way to do it except the messy string manipulation?

Reproducible data-frame code:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("1", "CASE", "{height=2.01, length=1.07, width=1.22}"),
        ("2", "PALLET", "{height=2.01, length=1.07, width=1.22}"),
    ],
    ["id", "containertype", "size"]
)

df.printSchema()
```

Comment: Can you paste the value a row of the csv? it looks like you have a JSON inside the column size, is that correct?

Comment: can you please add the reproducable dataframe code?

Comment: @Alfilercio yes. The data inside the column `size` is similar to json.

Comment: @MaheshGupta do you mean the code I am using read the data?

Comment: @biswasN they mean the shortest code to reproduce this dataframe in our spark sessions, and preferably the output of printSchema() too for adjusting the schema like yours if there is a mismatch. This will help us reproduce your exact issue and the likelihood of receiving better answers increases.

Comment: @anky I added the repro code in the question.

Comment: @biswasN Thanks, what is your spark version?

Comment: @anky Spark version: 3.2.1

Comment: Are the values always in the same format? Same values? Same order?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz yes

Answer (score -1):

If one of the columns is a JSON, you can parse it with the function `to_json`, which requires the column you want to parse, in your case size, and the schema that will result in the parsing, in this case:

```
schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("height",FloatType(),True), \
    StructField("length",FloatType(),True), \
    StructField("width",FloatType(),True)
])

df.withColumn("json", F.from_json(F.col("size"), schema))\
  .select(F.col("id"), F.col("containertype"), F.col("json.*"))
```

Comment: I added the reproducible dataframe code. You are assuming the `size` to be json but this is something similar to json but not exactly json. I am not sure if this is even any standard format.

Comment: replace the `=` with `:` and it can be parsed with the json format

Comment: Tried replacing the `=` with `:` but the values of height, width and length are coming as `null`.

Comment: Not even close. The keys are not qualified (E.g.  `height` instead of the desired `"height"`)

Answer (score -1):

Use a regex to extract the value

```
def getParameter(tag):
    return F.regexp_extract("size", tag+"=(\d+\.\d+)", 1).cast(FloatType()).alias(tag)

df.select(F.col("id"), F.col("containertype"), getParameter("height"), getParameter("length"), getParameter("width"))
```

Comment: Test your code (preferably before posting)